# Syntax error in running Matlab for-loop in Jupyter-notebook

Tags: matlab, for-loop, syntax-error, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Matlab script in jupyter notebook after importing matlab.engine as bellow:

```
for i =  1 : size(my_arr,1)
    ...
end
```

but it shows an error as:

```
 for i =  1 : size(my_arr,1)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

--
Later I figured out the kernel was set to python.

I did install matlab kernel and imported matlab.engine, but matlab kernel is not showing up as one of the options under Jupyter kerenls.

details:

```
[??? home]$ pip install matlab_kernel
Requirement already satisfied: matlab_kernel in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: metakernel>=0.18.0 in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=4.4.0 in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.tempfile in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>=4.2 in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from metakernel>=0.18.0->matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from metakernel>=0.18.0->matlab_kernel)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.weakref in ./ec2-user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from backports.tempfile->matlab_kernel)
```

Comment: How you are running that?. Can you detail the Jupyter Notebook and Matlab setup in there?

Comment: Just try simple matlab commands, like `disp('Hello World')` :):)

Comment: It doesn't work, disp is not defined, which I think is because of the kernel

Comment: Ha!. Now you are getting something.....

Comment: I have just added the details in the body of the question. thanks